# How to to implement mutex when I'm not able to disable interrupts?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I have to debug a piece of embedded system. I need to log some values allowing me reproducing code trace. But code is executed in two threads and I'm not able to disable interrupts or to prevent thread switching in any other way.
Is it possible in to implement in such environment a simple, safe mutex system for my global trace/logging engine in order to protect thread mixing in it?
How to do it?

Comment: Curious: why is the stuff listed under http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion#Software_solutions not suitable for you?

Comment: OK, what OS/tasker are you using to run your threads, because I've never met one without mutex/semaphore/event synchro.

Comment: use something like spinlock (active waiting)?

Comment: Are you sure you can't disable interrupts?

Comment: MicroC/OS; 4 ARM processors with partially shared RAM. System is really huge. My two threads are only a drops in the ocean. Yes: I can't disable interrupts. I implemented sth myself and now I see it is similar to Dekker's algorithm. It is not 100% trustworthy but probably enough.